# Python generic type annotation for pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, mypy, typeguards, nox

I am encountering a type checking error when running my code through `typeguard`.

I the following file in my package:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import pandas as pd

def col_sum(x: pd.Series[float]) -> pd.Series[float]:
   return x*(x.sum()-1)
```

Originally, I was using `pd.Series` for these type-hints, but when I run my code through `mypy` it requires that I explicitly subscript a type on the generic type, so I changed it to `pd.Series[float]` (this makes sense as it is more explicit and allows `mypy` to be certain that `x.sum()` is a float).

I also have a test script which performs some unit tests on this function.

However, my test-suite also includes running `pytest --typeguard-packages={MyPackage}`, but this is failing due to this function. Here is the error:

```
>   def col_sum(x: pd.Series[float]) -> pd.Series[float]:
E   TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

From my understanding, this is because `mypy` is importing the `pd.Series` from the `pandas-stubs` package which is a generic type (thus the requirement for the subscript). But `pytest` passes my code through the `install_import_hook()` function from `typeguard` which imports `pd.Series` as a class/type from the regular `pandas` package (which cannot be subscripted).

### How can I make my code pass *both* of these tests?

For clarity, I am using a trimmed down version of the [hypermodern cookiecutter template](https://cookiecutter-hypermodern-python.readthedocs.io/). I am using `nox` to manage my test-suite, and it runs the following Sessions:

```
* pre-commit -> Lint using pre-commit.
* safety -> Scan dependencies for insecure packages.
* mypy-3.10 -> Type-check using mypy.
* mypy-3.11 -> Type-check using mypy.
* tests-3.10 -> Run the test suite.
* tests-3.11 -> Run the test suite.
* coverage -> Produce the coverage report.
* typeguard -> Runtime type checking using Typeguard.
* xdoctest-3.10 -> Run examples with xdoctest.
* xdoctest-3.11 -> Run examples with xdoctest.
* docs-build -> Build the documentation.
```

All of which are passing, except for `typeguard`
Relevant package versions:

```
python = "3.10.11"
pandas = "2.1.4"
pandas-stubs = "2.1.4.231218"
typeguard = "4.1.5"
pytest = "7.4.3"
```

Comment: Patch `pd.Series` to add `__class_getitem__` method, it is a safe thing to do. `pd.Series.__class_getitem__ = lambda cls, *_: cls`